# How To Retrieve Value From JSON Result String in C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I parse below JSon string to get the value of RESULT & ERROR?

```
{
    "RESPONSE": [
        {
            "DT": "20210317",
            "I_NO": "1031021",
            "C_NO": "1021",
            "RESULT": "E",
            "DCODE": "2-B1",
            "ERROR": "[AMT] is mandatory."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your c# class for deserialization.

```
public class RESPONSE
{
    public string DT { get; set; }
    public string I_NO { get; set; }
    public string C_NO { get; set; }
    public string RESULT { get; set; }
    public string DCODE { get; set; }
    public string ERROR { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<RESPONSE> RESPONSE { get; set; }
}
```

Then Deserialize with [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```